# Change the field mapping for Number Type in Smartedit

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

I upgraded a SAP Hybris/Commerce from v1808 to v2205. In my custom SmartEdit-Extension I had a service that changed the editor template for the number type so that it could hold a value of 0. (I used this tutorial for it: [Customizing smartedit in hybris](https://dmitrykrivenko.blogspot.com/2018/08/customizing-smartedit-in-hybris.html)

Here is the code of the Service I created

```js
angular
    .module('newGenericEditorConfigurationServiceModule', ['editorFieldMappingServiceModule', 'newsmarteditContainerTemplates'])
    .service('newGenericEditorConfigurationService', function(editorFieldMappingService) {

        this.overrideDefaultEditorFieldMappings = function() {
            editorFieldMappingService.addFieldMapping('Number', null, null, {
                template: 'newNumberTemplate.html'
            });
        };

    });
```

Now the in v2205 Smartedit got upgraded from Angularjs to Angular and so the service is not working anymore.

Anyone has an idea how to do it? I already tried the code from here: [SPA Help Portal Trail](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/c7eda9f7e7104dd3b476f0de6f987a66/4c833c3697574af4b30402317d41eb65.html?locale=en-US)

```
    . . . . . . . . . 

import { SeEntryModule, EditorFieldMappingService, moduleUtils } from 'smarteditcommons';

. . . . . . ..
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, UpgradeModule],
    declarations: [],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: DummyInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        moduleUtils.bootstrap(
            (editorFieldMappingService: EditorFieldMappingService) => {
                // Adds the mapping. With this the new widget will be used for all fields of type "Range"
                editorFieldMappingService.addFieldMapping('Range', null, null, {
                    template: 'rangeFieldTemplate.html'
                });
            },
            [EditorFieldMappingService]
        )
    ]
})
export class SmartedittrailContainerModule {}
```

But it is not working I get still the same old template. Here [SAP Trail Creating a Custom Component](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/c7eda9f7e7104dd3b476f0de6f987a66/6c036ecad0de4e269fb50f2a41de1271.html?locale=en-US) they are using the same old AngularJs Syntax, but don't show how to wire it up to the new Angluar Module.

```
angular.module('trainingModule',  ['editorFieldMappingServiceModule', 'smartedittrail/cmssmarteditContainerTemplates'])
    .run(function(editorFieldMappingService) {
        editorFieldMappingService.addFieldMapping('Integer', null, null, {
            template: 'web/featureExtensions/smartedittrail/cmssmarteditContainer/integer-editorTemplate.html'
        });
    });
```

Anyone has an idea how to do it in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

copy NumberComponent.html from OTB and paste it inside customize folder

hybris\config\customize\modules\smartedit\smartedit\apps\smartedit-commons\src\components\genericEditor\widgets\NumberComponent

do required changes in the html file

ant customize
ant all